# Error on loading keras model with deeplearning4j

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, deeplearning4j

I have been struggling with loading my keras neural network model for my Android application with deeplearning4j for a while now. I have searched for solutions (as much as there are), but every solution brings up new errors and I just could not get this thing to work.

Anyways, I have trained a **NON** sequential model with keras in Python and saved it like this:

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

Now I am trying to import this model with deeplearning4j in Android Studio. I have tried many possible variants, but this is where I am now:

```
String modelPath = new ClassPathResource("res/raw/model.h5").getFile().getPath();
ComputationGraph model = KerasModelImport.importKerasModelAndWeights(modelPath)
```

This however triggers a following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/bytedeco/javacpp/hdf5;
```

As I understand, gradle is unable to resolve a dependency  `hdf5` from `org.bytedeco`, which I agree on as I have excluded `hdf5-platform` in my gradle build, but `hdf5` should not even be supported by Android as far as I know (?).

I have also tried to include `hdf5-platform` and run the same code, but doing so triggers another error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Platform "android-arm64" not supported by class org.bytedeco.javacpp.hdf5
```

I am rather new into gradle concepts and I do not know Android in depth, but seems that the problem is with my gradle dependencies. There is also limited amount of information about `deeplearning4j` and I could not figure out an alternative solution either.

I will also include my gradle dependencies I have from [this tutorial.](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-android)

```
implementation (group: 'org.deeplearning4j', name: 'deeplearning4j-core', version: '1.0.0-beta3') {
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'opencv-platform'
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'leptonica-platform'
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', module: 'hdf5-platform'
    exclude group: 'org.nd4j', module: 'nd4j-base64'
}
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3'
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-arm"
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-x86"
implementation group: 'org.nd4j', name: 'nd4j-native', version: '1.0.0-beta3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.3-1.4.3'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.4.3-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.76.0-1.4.3'
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.76.0-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.76.0-1.4.3', classifier: "android-arm64"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.76.0-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86"
implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.76.0-1.4.3', classifier: "android-x86_64"
```

**(How) should I change my dependencies to get this model importing to work?**

**Or should I change the way of importing my model somehow?**

Comment: HDF5 does not support Android. We need to save the model in DL4J format, and then we can load that on Android this way: https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nn-model-persistence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to load the model with TF Lite. To load a TensorFlow Keras model in Android or even iOS, you can use [TensorFlow Lite](https://ww.tensorflow.org/lite).

First, you need to convert your Keras ( .h5 ) model to a TFLite model ( .tflite )

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( 'model.h5' )
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open( 'model.tflite' , 'wb' ).write( tflite_model )
```

You may do the following :

1. If your model needs to be hosted on a cloud source which will be downloaded by your app then you can use [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/products/ml-kit/). For custom TFLite models read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models).
2. You can keep the TFLite model in the app's `assets` folder and then load the `MappedByteBuffer` of it. The TensorFlow Lite dependency for Android is available :

   ```
   implementation ‘org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0’
   ```

You can refer to this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#0) and this [article](https://link.medium.com/GItHM6QjQV).

You can load the MappedByteBuffer like :

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Activity activity) throws IOException {
  AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd(getModelPath());
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
  FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
  long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
  long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
  return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these resources and help! I'll try to implement this later on today and let you know if I finally get this to work =)

Comment: Solution to import model like this includes deprecated function in it, but for now it works like a charm!! If i figure out how work around it without using deprecated function, I will share it in Stack Overflow. Also got the prediction somewhat working on bitmap imput, but it needs some improvement still. Thank you for your answer, finally I can start moving on!